# Editing a vector with generated spinboxes in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am attempting to modify a vector of doubles with qdoublespinboxes generated by a class. I've tried many different solutions but I cannot figure out how to get the variable "i" inside of the connect lambda function. This is my first time dynamically creating ui elements in QT, so my approach may be very off.

**vector_editor.h**

```
#ifndef VECTOR_EDITOR_H
#define VECTOR_EDITOR_H

#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class vector_editor
{
public:
    vector_editor(QWidget* widget, vector<double>& v);
    QGridLayout* grid;
};

#endif // VECTOR_EDITOR_H
```

**vector_editor.cpp**

```
#include "vector_editor.h"

vector_editor::vector_editor(QWidget* widget, vector<double>& v)
{
    grid = new QGridLayout(widget);

    for(uint i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        QDoubleSpinBox* spinbox = new QDoubleSpinBox(widget);
        spinbox->setValue(v[i]);
        grid->addWidget(spinbox,i,0);
        QObject::connect(spinbox, QOverload<double>::of(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged), [&](double d){
            v[i] = d;
        });
    }
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "vector_editor.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    vector<double> v = vector<double>{1,2,3};
    vector_editor(ui->widget,v);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Whenever I attempt to change the value of one the spinboxes, the program crashes because the "i" variable is not yet initialized inside of the lambda function.

Comment: `i` is bound *by reference* and the for loop increments `i` until it is `v.size()`, and then *destructs* `i` at the end of the for loop.  The lambda then holds a dangling reference.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, it should we written as an answer.

Comment: How would one go around this? I understand the i is bound by reference and gets destructed

Comment: Redesign your code, don't use `vector_editor` class if you only want to invoke it's constructor once for the purpose of connecting the signals. As a rule of thumb, do not use `&` in the lambda capture, in your case it is enough to capture `i` by value.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda capture with `[&]` must be used carefully. The scope of what is being captured MUST survive through whenever the lambda is executed.

In your code, that absolutely is not the case. Your lambda gets executed when the value changes, and that is long, long after i no longer even exists.

Without testing the rest, if you change that capture to `[=]` (pass by value), it might work.

You can use `[&]` for things that execute immediately, such as the function passed to std::find_if. You can't use it for anything resembling a callback unless you're referencing a value you know will still exist by the time the lambda is called. Basically, if the call is deferred, `[&]` may be unsafe, and you need to be very careful.

Comment: If you change the capture to pass by value, then you can capture i, but the vector can no longer be updated in the lambda function.

Comment: @ColinMcGovern Hmm. It's passed into the method by reference. I don't know what the behavior is in that case. Does it continue to pass in by reference, and as long as the vector continues to exist, the reference works? I'm sure some people know the exact behavior, but it's something I'd have to write a test to see.